# Android: What is a difference between 'orientation' and 'screenLayout'?

Tags: android

There are 2 different constants that have same description (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#configChanges)

```
orientation  0x0080  The screen orientation has changed, that is the user has rotated the device. 
screenLayout  0x0100  The screen orientation has changed, that is the user has rotated the device.
```

Many sources suggest to specify:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

But should not it be:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never seen `screenLayout` used that way. My guess that it is a copy-and-paste error in the documentation.

Comment: Right, seems to be a typo in comments. Also this flag was not in 1.5, but can be seen in 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It is now fixed in the docs:

> orientation   0x0080    The screen orientation has changed, that is the
>   user has rotated the device.
>
> screenLayout  0x0100    The screen layout has changed. This might be
>   caused by a different display being activated.